# What to include when using GoogleHeaders in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I'm working on an application, which uses some google api components and my additional dependencies in build.gradle currently look like that:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

Still, I want to use GoogleHeaders class, but Android Studio cannot recognize it (Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleHeaders'):

```
public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
            headers.setApplicationName("AndroidHive-Places-Test");
            request.setHeaders(headers);
            JsonObjectParser parser = new JsonObjectParser(new JacksonFactory());
            request.setParser(parser);
        }
```

Should I add some more dependencies? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this link : http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders

Comment: GoogleHeaders is outdated and not in use now. Use HttpHeaders instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read about google API client libraries

[Google API client details](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)